# obstruction to lifting a projective bundle to a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Why is the obstruction,  to lifting a projective bundle to a (complex) vector bundle on a space $X$, given by an element 
$\alpha \in H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$?

Vector bundles are classified by $H^1(X, U(1))$ (e.g their transition functions give cocycles in the first Cech groups), and projective bundles by $H^1(X, PU(1))$. 
We have an exact sequence 
$$1 \to U(1) \to U(n) \to PU(n)\to 1$$ So the obstruction lies in $H^2(X, U(1))\simeq H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$ (I think these are isomorphic). Then maybe use the exponential sequence sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X^* \to 1$ to get
a map $$H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*) \to H^3(X, \mathbb{Z})$$
I don't see why this map is an isomorphism. Or maybe I am doing this all wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure, $X$ is any space right ? so $\mathcal{O}_X$ is just the sheaf of continuous function on $X$ ? In this case, this is a fine sheaf (if $X$ is paracompact), so its higher cohomology vanishes, and the long exact sequence induced by the exponential sequence tells you that $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)\rightarrow H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: On the other hand, if $X$ is supposed to be a complex manifold and $\mathcal{O}_X$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions, then this is not true that $H^2(X,U(1))=H^2(X,\mathcal{O}^*)$ (there is no holomorphy condition in the definition of $H^2(X,U(1))$.)

Comment: @Roland Thank you! You found the source of my confusion. Yes, $X$ is just a space, and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is just the continuous functions. I was thinking (incorrectly) that the higher cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_X$ need not vanish, but that's if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on a complex manifold, which is not what $\mathcal{O}_X$ is here/

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped ;)

Comment: Just to remark, assuming that your space $X$ is sufficiently nice @Roland you can actually show that $\mathrm{Br}(X)$ is just the torsion in $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)[\mathrm{tors}]=H^3_{\mathrm{sing}}(X,\mathbb{Z})[tors]$